# How to get image in plugin

Tags: magento2

I have a image, that situated

```
vendor/mymodule/magento2/Checkout/view/frontend/web/images/dynamicimageweb.gif
```

And in the plugin I need to set URL, that will open this image and which I will insert in the future in src. How i can do it?

**EDIT**

Comment: I think that the correct folder to insert the image if this is public will be pub/media

Comment: @raumatbel when I deploy static it is in pub/media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getViewFileUrl()`.

```
echo $this->getViewFileUrl('VendorName_Modulename::images/dynamicimageweb.gif');
echo $block->getViewFileUrl('VendorName_Modulename::images/dynamicimageweb.gif');
```

Be sure that your file should be in pub static content data , it not created then do setup upgrade and deploy.

Comment: ty. From what class should I extend?

Comment: No need to extend any class, getViewFileUrl() is global function , you can use using $this object.

Comment: vendor/accord/magento2/Checkout/view/frontend/web/images/dynamicimageweb.gif it is $this->getViewFileUrl('Accord_Checkout::images/dynamicimageweb.gif')?

Comment: but in the static directory path is pub/static/frontend/Accord/base/en_GB/Accord_Checkout/images/dynamicimageweb.gif

Comment: $this->getViewFileUrl('Accord_Checkout::images/dynamicimageweb.gif') is correct.

Comment: I think U a not right because my $this is empty

Comment: I edited my question and insert code from plugin

Comment: What error you are facing in image after using getViewFileUrl() ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79431/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and--).